# Unable to redirect using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect http to https using htaccess. I tried many solutions posted here, but have no luck. I just do not know what is wrong in this file?

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: mod_rewrite not enabled

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled on your server? sudo a2enmod rewrite

Comment: I got answer form host support that it is enabled

Answer (score 0):

I got answer form host support that it is enabled. Now it is clear, that this line RewriteEngine On should be added before  line IfModule mod_rewrite. Strangely, maybe it is too easy, but I nowhere found this advice.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your answer was very clear that you didn't enabled `mod_rewrite` and what you said regarding the solution is completely wrong unless there is unusual configuration at your HOST .

So , when i put this `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`  it means that if the `mod_rewrite` is enabled apply the following code .

And when i put `RewriteEngine On` it means activate `mod_rewrite` and it has no issue with this check `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` to be after it or before .

Moreover , you could be able to put your code without `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` but if the `mod_rewrite` is not enabled , Apache will get crash , so when you put it and regarding whatever reason ,The  `mod_rewrite` being disabled nothing will happen and server will work normal even not applying these rule